# How to run an ionic command like "ionic serve" using a button click while the node server is running

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework, ionic2

My problem is that i want to send a command to node js server to run the ionic command when ever i click on the button. I merged two projects but they are not working with simple routing. I think it need to run ionic server at backend

Answer (score 0):

I think we can help you to find an better alternative to your problem with more information

But the solution that you wanted is :
You can do an http call on the click event of your button to your node js server and run your command with child_process module

doc : https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Comment: is it only solution to my problem. i would glad to have some better alternative?

Comment: Your problem is switch to both ionic project ?      You can just build the both project in produdction mode . "ionic build browser --prod --release". Take the content of the www folders in platforms/browser. Push them to your production server and you just have to switch between the both index.html file. The last solution is a real merge between the code of both projects and maintain a single project